# Laravel MySQL relationship not working

Tags: mysql, laravel

I actually finish programing a website and when i do the `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` on my local MySQL database everything worked perfectly, but now that i'm on my real database it's not working at all the relationship. You can actually see the problem even on the Sequel Pro interface like this:

[image]

And here is working just fine on mi local DB

[image]

I'm hosting my DB on bluehost i don't know if that have anything to do with the problem or if the problem is something with the DB user and not with Laravel

Here is an example of what it looks like when i create this table:

[image]

Comment: What's the storage engine used for your live DB? if It's MyISAM, you'll have a read-performance win, but no relational constraints what so ever... InnoDB is what you want there

Comment: What i did, was import the DB from my localhost, but how can i set the default ENGINE as InnoDB for each table?

Comment: So actually your answer was one part of the solution, the other part was to add this line to migration `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';` that's how you set the InnoDB engine for the table on Laravel. Thanks

Comment: @NelsonCandia Also why you have those in different functions? You could have it (the foreign keys) when `creating` the table `role_user`. Plus, if you don't want to use `$table->engine = innodb` you can define it `/laravel/config/database.php` ~40-60 line -> `mysql=>engine=>`